# Safe to cache unencrypted API keys in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, security, google-cloud-functions

Our Google cloud Function has access to an encrypted API key which it can unencrypt by using an external service. Once the API key is unencrypted, is it then safe to cache the API key as a global variable so that in cases where a Google Cloud Function is reused, the unencrypted variable can be used instead of contacting the unencryption service?

**EDIT:**

Our thinking is that the function will use an unencrypted version of the API key when running (i.e. store it in its memory for use) and that it's cache, I believe, is in memory and per function, which to the best of my knowledge would make it no less safe to cache the unencrypted API key per function than get it and unencrypt it on every function invocation?

'Safe' was a bad word choice - there is no such thing as safe, everything is, to an extent, a balancing act.

Comment: This really depends on your definition of "safe".  What are your concerns that would make this "unsafe"?

Comment: Yes, true, no such thing as safe, everything is, to an extent, a balancing act. Can't put our setup here - to the best of our knowledge, we have implemented a secure way to store and use our API keys. Our thinking is that the function will use an unencrypted version of the API key when running (i.e. store it in its memory for use) and that it's cache, I believe, is in memory and per function, which to my knowledge would make it no less safe to cache the unencrypted API key per function than get it and unencrypt it on every function invocation? Thanks for chiming in again - really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statistically speaking, the longer you hold sensitive information in memory, the easier it is for a bad actor to get a hold of it.  But you can never really eliminate the chance of this happening.  The issue is really how this bad actor gets into Cloud Functions.  The moment this becomes a possibility, you've got a problem.  This can happen by trusting third party code into your deployment, or someone getting a hold of your project's admin credentials or a lapse in security at Google.

But if you assume that there is no possibility of a bad actor entering the system, it doesn't really matter how long you hold on to something in memory, since you trust every bit of code that could access it (and of course Google for providing that memory).

The memory isn't held strictly "per function".  It would be held "per function per instance".  Depending on the load, you could have many server instances all decrypting and holding sensitive information.  But the code running on the instance would only be triggered from the one function and never others.

Caching API keys in memory in this manner does make changing API keys a bit more complex if you had to quickly change them i.e. due to a leak - a way round could be to also store a timestamp in a global variable and invalidate the key after x amount of time has passed or to restart all of the functions so the memory cache is cleared and fresh versions of the API keys are fetched, which would happen if you push a new version of the function to Google Cloud Functions

Comment: Just to add to this for anyone else, it may be worth adding in that it does make changing API keys a bit more complex if you had to quickly change them - a way round could be to also store a timestamp in a global variable and invalidate the key after x amount of time has passed or to somehow restart all of the functions, which I assume would happen if you push a new version of the function to Google Cloud Functions